# R - two data frame columns to list of key-value pairs

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame

```
DF1 <- data.frame("a" = c("a", "b", "c"), "b" = 1:3)
```

What is the easiest way to turn this into a list?

```
DF2 <- list("a" = 1, "b" = 2, "c" = 3)
```

It must be really simple but I can't find out the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `setNames` and `as.list`

```
DF2 <- setNames(as.list(DF1$b), DF1$a)
```

Comment: I think they should also consider using a vector instead of a list, since every element is a scalar of the same type: `with(DF1,setNames(b,a))`

Answer (score 0):

The tidy 2023 way would be to use [deframe](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/enframe.html?q=deframe#ref-usage):

```r
tibble(
  key = c("key1", "key2", "key3"),
  value = c("val1", "val2", "val3")
) %>%
deframe()

#   key1   key2   key3 
# "val1" "val2" "val3" 

tibble(
  key = c("key1", "key2", "key3"),
  value = c("val1", "val2", "val3")
) %>%
deframe() %>%
as.list()

# $key1
# [1] "val1"
#
# $key2
# [1] "val2"
#
# $key3
# [1] "val3"
```